# How to load a text file and store into data structure

Tags: matlab, text, text-parsing

I have a 'text' file having content as follows:

`012abc3cb7503bddef3ff59e0e52fd79.jpg 160.073318 18.588472 14.246923 8.054444 6.600504 6.261390 5.838249 4.447019 3.639888 3.357715 2.996645 2.910991 2.574769 2.527163 2.343448 2.264113 2.176161 2.088773 1.915582 1.902159 1.836033 1.725432 1.667595 1.633245 1.557424 1.542059 1.434280 1.430181 1.321047 1.302652 1.272890 1.261313 1.188892 1.138115 1.114376 1.070352 1.044311 1.025954 0.993622 0.988920 0.969866 0.933977 0.931669 0.913624 0.882856 0.876036 0.840088 0.822686 0.814072 0.787075 0.781157 0.778171 0.763771 0.748851 0.740975 0.708208 0.691589 0.688566 0.664124 0.659779 0.644820 0.623200 0.614799 0.607180 0.590615 0.578751 0.57...........`

Each row represents an image (instance) with the first column being image name, remaining 240 columns being the feature-vector of the image.

How can I load this file in MATLAB and store the image names into 'names' variable and the 240 values into a 'histogram' variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
str = textread('tmp.txt','%s');
str = reshape(str,241,[]).';
names = str(:,1); %'// cell array of strings with image names
histogram = str2double(str(:,2:end)); %// each row refers to an image
```

Comment: but now the 'names' contains the image name and then the 240 real values too

Comment: @VarunDas I'm not sure I follow your comment. But I've made a correction that might related to that

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to do it with `textscan` and `repmat` so you can avoid conversion from strings:

```
Nfeatures = 240;
fid = fopen('text.txt');
format = ['%s ' repmat('%f', [1 Nfeatures])];
imageFeatureCell = textscan(fid, format, 'CollectOutput', true);
fclose(fid);
```

A test on a file with 7 rows:

```
>> fileData
fileData = 
    {7x1 cell}    [7x240 double]
```

Move into your desired variables:

```
names = fileData{1};      % names{1} contains first file name, etc.
histogram = fileData{2};  % histogram(1,:) contains first file's features
```

Comment: The `repmat` command puts 240 `'%f'` int the format string. Then the `'CollectOutput'` option puts all the same data type together in a single cell.